# How do you plot smooth components of different GAMs in same panel?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam, mgcv

I have two GAMs which have the same predictor variables but different independent variables. I would like to combine the two GAMs to a set of plots where the smooth component (partial residuals) of each predictor variable are in the same panel (differentiated with e.g. color). Reproducible example:

```
# Required packages
require(mgcv)
require(mgcViz)

# Dataset
data("swiss")

# GAM models
fit1 <- mgcv::gam(Fertility ~ s(Examination) + s(Education), data = swiss)
fit2 <- mgcv::gam(Agriculture ~ s(Examination) + s(Education), data = swiss)

# Converting GAM objects to a gamViz objects
viz_fit1 <- mgcViz::getViz(fit1)
viz_fit2 <- mgcViz::getViz(fit2)

# Make plotGAM objects
trt_fit1 <- plot(viz_fit1, allTerms = T) + l_fitLine()
trt_fit2 <- plot(viz_fit2, allTerms = T) + l_fitLine()

# Print plots
print(trt_fit1, pages = 1)
print(trt_fit2, pages = 1)
```

Plot of fit1 looks like this:

[image: trt_fit1]

And fit2 like this:

[image: trt_fit2]

So I would like to combine the two Examinations into one panel, and the two Educations into another one, showing the independent variable (from different GAMs) with different color/linetype.

Comment: But won't your two outcome variables have different y axis scales? Are you wanting a secondary axis? Or can the two outcomes be represented on the same scale?

Comment: They will have different y-axis scales, that's correct. However, they have very similar ranges so they could still easily be interpreted with the same y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do this using my {gratia}  and the `compare_smooths()` function:

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")

# Dataset 
data("swiss") 

# GAM models 
fit1 <- gam(Fertility ~ s(Examination) + s(Education),
            data = swiss, method = "REML")
fit2 <- gam(Agriculture ~ s(Examination) + s(Education),
            data = swiss, method = "REML")

# create and object that contains the info to compare smooths
comp <- compare_smooths(fit1, fit2)

# plot
draw(comp)
```

This produces

[image]

The output from `compare_smooth()` is a nested data frame (tibble)

```
r$> comp                                                                        
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  model smooth         type  by    data              
  <chr> <chr>          <chr> <chr> <list>            
1 fit1  s(Education)   TPRS  NA    <tibble [100 × 3]>
2 fit2  s(Education)   TPRS  NA    <tibble [100 × 3]>
3 fit1  s(Examination) TPRS  NA    <tibble [100 × 3]>
4 fit2  s(Examination) TPRS  NA    <tibble [100 × 3]>
```

So if you want to do customising of the plot etc, you'll need to know how to work with nested data frames or just do

```r
library("tidyr")
unnest(comp, data)
```

which gets you:

```
r$> unnest(comp, data)                                                          
# A tibble: 400 × 8
   model smooth       type  by      est    se Education Examination
   <chr> <chr>        <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     1.19  3.48      1             NA
 2 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     1.37  3.20      1.53          NA
 3 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     1.56  2.94      2.05          NA
 4 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     1.75  2.70      2.58          NA
 5 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     1.93  2.49      3.10          NA
 6 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     2.11  2.29      3.63          NA
 7 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     2.28  2.11      4.15          NA
 8 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     2.44  1.95      4.68          NA
 9 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     2.59  1.82      5.20          NA
10 fit1  s(Education) TPRS  NA     2.72  1.71      5.73          NA
# … with 390 more rows
```

To create your own plots then, we proceed from the unnested data frames and add the confidence interval

```
ucomp <- unnest(comp, data) %>%
  add_confint()
```

Then plot each panel in turn

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
p_edu <- ucomp |>
  filter(smooth == "s(Education)") |> # <-- only one comparison at a time
  ggplot(aes(x = Education, y = est)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci, fill = model),
                alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = model)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +   # <-- change fill scale
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + # <-- change colour scale
    geom_rug(data = swiss,                  # <-- rug
             mapping = aes(x = Education, y = NULL),
             sides = "b", alpha = 0.4) +  
    labs(title = "s(Education)", y = "Estimate",
         colour = "Model", fill = "Model")

p_exam <- ucomp |>
  filter(smooth == "s(Examination)") |>
  ggplot(aes(x = Examination, y = est)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower_ci, ymax = upper_ci, fill = model),
                alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = model)) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +   # <-- change fill scale
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1") + # <-- change colour scale
    geom_rug(data = swiss,                  # <-- rug
             mapping = aes(x = Examination, y = NULL),
             sides = "b", alpha = 0.4) +  
    labs(title = "s(Examination)", y = "Estimate",
         colour = "Model", fill = "Model")
```

Now use the {patchwork} package to put the plots together

```r
library("patchwork")
p_edu + p_exam + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

which produces

[image]

This is all using {ggplot2} so you'll need to look at other scales if you want more control over the colours `?scale_fill_manual` for example or provide other ready-made discrete scales if you want to use an existing palette.

I could make some of this easier in {gratia} - I could allow users to provide a scale to be used for the colour and fill, and also if they supply the raw data I could draw the rugs too.

Comment: This is a great and useful answer! I'm just not sure how to get the plot itself, to change line colors, etc... I didn't understand how to get it from the unnest() function.  How do we get the plot only?

Comment: @mtao You can't change the colours etc on the plot produced by the `draw()` method. If you want to produced your own plots, it's pretty trivial if you know ggplot2. Is it the latter you want to know how to do? If yes, I can add something to my answer

Comment: yes, I would like to create my own plots, but based on the outcome of draw() (e.g. to edit colors and add rugs). I tried before to do this in a ggplot (adding the values per model) but I failed to include the SE properly...

Comment: @mtao Done; added a fully worked example showing how to modify the colour/fill scales and add a rug to each panel

Comment: Is there a way to use this code exactly but considering the intercept in the y-axis? So, the same that is done with "shift" in the function "plot(my_model, shift = coef(my_model)[1])".

Comment: @mtao Do you want to include the uncertainty in the estimate of the constant term or just shift everything up? If the latter, just use `mutate()` on `ucomp` to add `coef(model)[1L]` to the `est`, `lower_ci` and `upper_ci` variables. If you want the former, then I would suggest using `fitted_values()` with the same data slice (created by `data_slice()`) on each model to generate the relevant smooths. If you need more help then ask a new question about this and if you reply here I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did create a new question, as I tried both options and didn't seem to work out very well. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76227580/gam-plots-editing-the-y-axis-to-include-the-intercept-uncertainty

Answer (score 3):

If you want them in the same plot, you can pull the data from your fit with `trt_fit1[["plots"]][[1]]$data$fit` and plot them yourself. I looked at the plot style from the [`mgcViz` github](https://github.com/mfasiolo/mgcViz/blob/master/R/plot_mgcv_smooth_2D.R). You can add a second axis or scale as necessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)
exam_dat <- 
  bind_rows(trt_fit1[["plots"]][[1]]$data$fit %>% mutate(fit = "Fit 1"), 
            trt_fit2[["plots"]][[1]]$data$fit %>% mutate(fit = "Fit 2"))
  

ggplot(data = exam_dat, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = fit)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Examination", y = "s(Examination)") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

To simply get them on the same panel, you could use `gridExtra` as `fit1` and `fit2` have a `ggplot` object.

```r
gridExtra::grid.arrange(
  trt_fit1[["plots"]][[2]]$ggObj, 
  trt_fit2[["plots"]][[2]]$ggObj, 
  nrow = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Any idea on how to add the confidence intervals from the GAM? I tried calculating them with the "ty" value and then +- 2*se but doesn't seem to work well...

Comment: @mtao You could use the `gratia` package described by the author above. You can use 2*se, but it's done with `predict` for pointwise intervals (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33327/confidence-interval-for-gam-model).  You can also compute simultaneous confidence interval through simulation https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/12/15/simultaneous-interval-revisited/